# GoogleMaps API v2 - Tracking only via GPS

Tags: android, gps, google-maps-api-2

i want solve problem, and i cant figure how. I need to my app track position only via GPS, no tracking with network and internet. Now, when i am outside, i have wrong position, came to me with very big divergence. Need locate with 100 meters accuracy.

Here is my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private boolean aFoundMyLocation;

private Document aDocument;
private GoogleMap aGoogleMap;
private GoogleDirection aGoogleDirection;

private LatLng aCurrentLocation;
...

@InjectView(R.id.txt_distance)
TextView txtDistance;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    // initial map center settings
    aTargetLocation = new LatLng(49.199362, 18.737382);
    aGoogleDirection = new GoogleDirection(this);
    aFoundMyLocation = false;

    // inflate mapFragment
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

...

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    aGoogleMap = googleMap;
    aGoogleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    aGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    aGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            aCurrentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            ...
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

and part of my Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
...

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="..." />

</application>
```

Can someone gave me a advice, how can edit this for tracking actual position only via GPS with 100 meters accuracy ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
protected LocationManager locationManager;

//use this on your onCreate Method

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Comment: on requestLocationUpdates, last param context listener cant resolve, have idea what i must change ?

Comment: "this" refers to the app's locationlistener. Make sure you have this: `import android.location.LocationListener`

Comment: ok thanks, bad import, my was from google.android.gms.maps ... i will go try it outside

Comment: Also your MainActivity should implement LocationListener, like this for example `public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener`